# Perché una persona scocciata dice "sa"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Ogni tanto sento uno dei miei amici dire "sa" quando ha fretta,vuole fare qualcosa, non vuole parlare oppure aspettare. Esempio: "Sa, andiamo". Lo dice molto più sovente se è scocciato.

Ho chiesto in giro cosa volesse dire *sa* e mi è stato risposto "È come dire **su**, ma non è **su**, è proprio **sa**".

La parola "su" la comprendo, vuol dire *alziamoci* o *andiamo*. Invece "sa" non la trovo da nessuna parte e non ne capisco il significato.

È solo la vocale sbagliata, detta male? Oppure è una parola diversa?

Comment: Non credo che essere scocciati abbia particolare importanza.

Comment: Diciamo che puo' dipendere dallo stato d'animo di una persona ma non totalmente. Per esempio se una persona è stufa/scocciata di stare in un determinato posto, potrebbe dire: *SA, ma che facciamo? Andiamo?!*. Ad ogni modo puo' essere usata anche in altri contesti.

Comment: Ho ripristinato la _tag_ “regional” perché sicuramente a Roma, e probabilmente fuori dal Nordovest, “sa” non si sente dire. Io ne ho appreso l'esistenza da questa domanda.

Answer (score 3):

La parola **sa** è un'espressione dialettale del Nord Italia, principalmente della regione Piemonte

Il significato è quello che hai indicato tu, quindi "Sa, andiamo?" come per dire "cosa facciamo ? Andiamo? ".

Potrebbe essere sostituita come dici tu da **su** oppure da **dai** secondo il contesto.

Esempio:

> Sa, ora mi alzo dalla sedia

Comment: Si usa anche "cià" - non so se ha un significato particolare per entrambe; sospetto una derivazione onomatopeica; in italiano l'esortazione sarebbe "orsù".

Comment: io sono del Piemonte e gran parte delle persone anziane, quindi quelle che utilizzano sovente il dialetto dicono la parola "SA". Diciamo che "sa" e "nè" sono due espressioni molto usate dalle nostre parti. Anche se pian piano, il dialetto sta scomparendo sempre di più, portandosi via tutte queste espressioni quasi onomatopeiche.

Comment: Quindi è specifica e probabilmente confinata al dialetto piemontese. Forse è il caso di specificarlo nella tua risposta.

Comment: Sinceramente ho sentito dire SA anche da Lombardi/Liguri... ad ogni modo, specifico la mia risposta.

Comment: L'ho sentito da lombardi (non da piemontesi, ma non ne ho grande esperienza).

Comment: esatto @egreg , credo sia utilizzato più o meno in tutto il nord italia, ma prendete questa informazione con le pinze.

Comment: @Liiuc Direi Piemonte e Lombardia; forse Liguria, ma non il Levante. Escluderei anche Bergamasca, Bresciano e Mantovano.

Comment: @Liiuc: In che senso “onomatopeiche”? Quale suono imitano?

Comment: Di certo non l'ho mai sentita usare in Veneto.

Comment: @DaG: È stato Riccardo a dire che è "onomatopeica".

Comment: @Charo: Ah, è vero, lo diceva anche Riccardo.

Comment: @egreg Mia zia è bresciana, vive in provincia di Bergamo ed è solita dire «sa».